# TSQL syntax for enclosing search terms within brackets

Tags: t-sql, search, sql-server-2005, sql-like

I believe `[` and `]` are special characters when using with `LIKE` clause in TSQL( SQlserver 2005 if it matters). How do i escape the search term in the stored procedure, i did below but does not return valid records even while exists

```
SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%['+ @searchedTerm +']'
```

So which is the valid thing to do, when searching like above??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to escape the opening (not the closing) bracket like this:

```
LIKE '%[[]' + @searchedTerm + ']'
```

The [MSDN page for LIKE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179859%28SQL.90%29.aspx) has a section "Using Wildcard Characters As Literals"

Edit, after comment

- `LIKE '[[]cap]%'` searches for a name containing the string [cap]
- `LIKE '[wel]%'` searches for a name containing *one of* the letters `w`, `e` or `l`

Comment: wow it's you How do you do? btw if the search term contained column names then it should be enclosed within `[` & `]` right? so i tried this to get no results `select * from product where name LIKE '[[]cap]%'` but this `select * from product where productname LIKE '[wel]%'` seems to work u got any idea what's missing

Comment: @Deeptechtons: updated answer. Please read the MSDN article on how to use LIKE

Comment: accepted as answer, but how do i escape the column names in searchterm?

Comment: Its possible that column names are not always quoted in brackets

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @searchedTerm as varchar(50); 
SET @searchedTerm = 'TEST VALUE'

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%[[]' + @searchedTerm +']'
```

Comment: yours is a neater example of Gbn's so i will have to voteup but not the answer

Answer (score 0):

try this:

SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Column LIKE '%/['+ @searchedTerm +']' {escape '/'}

Comment: @Deeptechtons: did you at least try my answer?